# WindowsError: Exception: access violation reading 0x00000000 trying to get return from windows DLL API call

Tags: python, ctypes, byref

Using the following code:

```
from ctypes import *

test = WinDLL('My.dll')
test.My_API_call_fetch.argtypes = [POINTER(c_long)]
rtn = c_long()
test.My_API_call_fetch(byref(rtn))
```

I get the WindowsError: Exception: access violation reading 0x000000000 and have ran out of ideas. Can anyone offer some suggestions?

I can do any API calls that do not return anything without errors.

Comment: What's the C function's prototype? Maybe it takes a `long **`.

Comment: 0x000000000 hints at a nullpointer.